# MechanicalSoup action difficulty with forms

Tags: python, html, forms, mechanize, mechanicalsoup

First, I am French so if there are mistakes in my english I'm sorry.
So here is my problem, I have hard time with mechanicalsoup. So here is my HTML page:

```
<form class="XFYOY" method="post"><h2 class="vvzhL ">Inscrivez-vous pour voir les photos et vidéos de vos amis.</h2>
```

Here are just the first line. I want to create an automatic form but there is not action and I don't know what to put in browser.select_form():

```
browser.select_form('form[action=/post]')
browser["emailOrPhone"] = "0689754327"
browser["fullName"] = "Jean"
```

What I put is not working because the form I have don't have a action.
What can I do ?

Thx,
Lazare

Comment: Open the requests tab in your browser. Then try submitting the form. A network request will be made. Study that and just duplicate it changing whatever you need.

Comment: Hey, Thank got your rep ! But i don't understand what I have to do could you describe or explain to me please ?

Comment: Can you provide the Link to the website?

Comment: It's Instagram website. Here is the link: https://www.instagram.com/ . It's the form to create a new account

Comment: See https://imgur.com/s91T0u6 . It has the URL you need to access and the request headers you need to set.

Comment: So I have to change the command ? Cause I don't see an action button.. Could you send me the command I have to write please ? Thank your for your time and your help ;p

Comment: Rishav what do I have to do ? I don't know what to do with this URL...