# Mechanicalsoup difficulty with browser.select_form()

Tags: python, html, mechanize, mechanicalsoup

First, I am French so if there are mistakes in my english I'm sorry. So here is my problem, I have hard time with mechanicalsoup. So here is my HTML page:

`<form class="XFYOY" method="post"><h2 class="vvzhL ">Inscrivez-vous pour voir les photos et vidéos de vos amis.</h2>`

Here are just the first line. I want to create an automatic form but there is not action and I don't know what to put in browser.select_form():

`browser.select_form('form[action=/post]')`
`browser["fullName"] = "Jean"`

What I put is not working because the form I have don't have a action. What can I do ?

Thx, Lazare

Comment: You've posted essentially 3 times the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50664029/difficulty-with-mechanicalsoup-forms https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50660786/mechanicalsoup-action-difficulty-with-forms. Can you select the right one and delete the duplicates? Thanks,

Comment: If it's just that form on the page then you can use browser.select_form() and just not pass it anything